# Assign multiple different mocks in one line

Tags: python, mocking

I can initialize multiple mock objects using the mock library like this:

```
import mock

a = mock.Mock()
b = mock.Mock()
c = mock.Mock()
```

And these are all different objects:

```
>>> a
<Mock id='4420729264'>
>>> b
<Mock id='4420729096'>
>>> c
<Mock id='4421494320'>
```

But if I use something like

`a=b=c=mock.Mock()` then they will be the same object.

Is there a way in python to initialize these to three different instances of the object, however in only one line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a, b, c = mock.Mock(), mock.Mock(), mock.Mock()
```